# Unable to access react environment variables using process.env

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React App, I use a .env file to keep some API keys. However when I tried to access those variables using `process.env` the values seem to be `undefined`.

I start the app using below command.

```
yarn build; cd dist; static-server --index ./login/index.html -p 1234
```

I tried restarting server, removing dist folder and rebuilding but didn't work.

This is where I access the variables.
In constants.js

```
const MY_API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY;
// some more consts here

module.exports = {MY_API_KEY};
```

However when I did `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY)` in constants.js file, it printed the key to console and `MY_API_KEY` was initialized to correct value.

What could have gone wrong here ?

Comment: why yo do : `module.exports = {MY_API_KEY};` instead `module.exports = MY_API_KEY;` ?

Comment: have you installed `dotenv` package to extract the data from .env file?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing environment variables in React is a bit different from how you would do it when working in a Node environment.

You need to configure Webpack to handle environment variables and also install an NPM library for loading these variables.

First install `node-env-file`, this allows you to load your environment variables.

Then for the Webpack part, you need to do this:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: '"production"',
      REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY)
    }
  }),
]
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same by updating .env file in React App ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Following [this](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env) approach to have environment variables in .env file ?

Comment: I think so if you are using create react app.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your environment variables correctly as described in https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

Since it prints the right value when you `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY)`, it sounds like an import/export issue.

try

```js
export const MY_API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY;
```

```js
import {MY_API_KEY} from '../my-environment-variables'
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an import issue as the app can access the assigned value to `MY_API_KEY` if it reads `process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY`. The issue is that this happens intermittently.